# django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied despite having supplied password in settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to do python manage.py migrate to do migrations for my django app but i keep getting this error even though i have supplied the db name, user, password in settings.py.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'accountant',
        'USER': 'json',
        'PASSWORD': '******',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 93, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 191, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 59, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 49, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 162, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 135, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 98, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 130, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 119, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/home/json/anaconda3/envs/py33/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? The `ENGINE` setting for PostgreSQL has been `django.db.backends.postgresql` for quite some time

Comment: My app requires django version 1.8. But im getting the same error even when i try the django.db.backends.postgresql ENGINE

Comment: Best guess is the `settings.py` that has the database parameters you show in your question is not the one being used. Either that portion of the settings is being overriden by another settings file or you have something like `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=other_settings.py` loaded in the environment where you are doing the migration.